# Why is Xcode complaining when I wrap this let in an if statement?

Tags: swift

I have the following working code in my app:

```
func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping ([JsonFile.JsonBonuses]?) -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/ExampleData.json")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil, let data = data {
                do {
                    let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFile.self, from: data)
                    completed(posts.bonuses)
                    self.defaults.set(posts.meta.version, forKey: "jsonVersion")
                    print("URLSession did not fail")
                    print("JSON Version Set to \(posts.meta.version)")
                } catch {
                    print("Can't decode JSON: \(error)")
                }
            } else {
                print("downloadJSON completed")
                completed(nil)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

I am wanting to change that URL to a different one based on a UserDefaults setting. So I wrapped the let url in an if statement like this:

```
if devModeStatus == true {
            let url = URL(string: "https://otherexample.com/Example2Data.json")!
        } else if devModeStatus == false {
            let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/ExampleData.json")!
        } else {
            print("Invalid Dev Status encountered!")
            return
        }
```

However when I do that, Xcode complains about "Use of unresolved identifier 'url'; did you mean 'erfl'?" on the line that says `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in`

I'm not sure why it is complaining about this change. I use that same if/else logic else where to print a status message at first load of this view, so I know the variable is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `url` declaration dies within those `if`, `else-if` scopes. You need to declare your `url` first then modify it. Also, since `devModeStatus` is a boolean value, the else case will never be reached, so no need for third path. Update your code as following:

```
let url: URL

if devModeStatus {
    url = URL(string: "https://otherexample.com/Example2Data.json")!
} else {
    url = URL(string: "http://example.com/ExampleData.json")!
}
```

Comment: `let url = URL(string: devModeStatus ? "https://otherexample.com/Example2Data.json" : "http://example.com/ExampleData.json")!`.

Comment: That gave me an initialization error, however @maddy's method worked perfectly. Thank you both!